# Making fields mandatory based on decision in Docusign

Tags: docusignapi

I have two fields SSN and EIN. Its mandatory for the user to fill in either the SSN or the EIN field. How would you go about doing this in docusign?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `conditional fields` in DocuSign.  For instance, you can have a radio button group with two radios (only one may be selected) and, based on which one the recipient selects, you either show the SSN field or you show the EIN field.

It's probably easiest if you create a DocuSign template and configure this logic through the UI and test.  Once you have that sorted out then I'd attempt doing it through the API.

Answer (score 2):

On the form you could have a hidden field for SSN and EIN, then have a drop down that allows them to choose if they are entering an SSN or EIN.  Then make which ever of the hidden fields show when they choose SSN or EIN.

Example: You have a Data field, that will only show when they Choose SSN from the drop down box.  Then you have a Data field that only shows when they choose EIN from the drop down box.